# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always return false .NET CORE C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, jwt, razor-pages

I´ve tried `var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(GetUserClaims(user), token);` but i don´t know how to use it

My startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            });
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

            //Provide a secret key to Encrypt and Decrypt the Token
            var SecretKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes
                 ("YourKey-2374-OFFKDI940NG7:56753253-tyuw-5769-0921-kfirox29zoxv");
            //Configure JWT Token Authentication
            services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
            {
                auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(token =>
            {
                token.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                token.SaveToken = true;
                token.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    //Same Secret key will be used while creating the token
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(SecretKey),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    //Usually, this is your application base URL
                    ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:45092/",
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    //Here, we are creating and using JWT within the same application.
                    //In this case, base URL is fine.
                    //If the JWT is created using a web service, then this would be the consumer URL.
                    ValidAudience = "http://localhost:45092/",
                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

My Service.cs

```
public string LoginUser(string UserID, string Password)
        {
            var user = UserList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == UserID);
            if (user == null)
                return null;
            if (Password == user.Password)
            {
                //Authentication successful, Issue Token with user credentials 
                //Provide the security key which is given in 
                //Startup.cs ConfigureServices() method 
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes
                ("YourKey-2374-OFFKDI940NG7:56753253-tyuw-5769-0921-kfirox29zoxv");
                //Generate Token for user 
                var JWToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: "http://localhost:45092/",
                    audience: "http://localhost:45092/",
                    claims: GetUserClaims(user),
                    notBefore: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).DateTime,
                    expires: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)).DateTime,
                    //Using HS256 Algorithm to encrypt Token  
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials
                    (new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                );
                string token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(JWToken);
                //var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(GetUserClaims(user), token);
                //return claimsIdentity;
                return token;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private List<User> UserList = new List<User>
        {
            new User {
                    UserId = "jsmith@email.com",
                    Password = "test", Email = "jsmith@email.com",
                    FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith",
                    Phone = "356-735-2748", AccesLevel = "Director",
                    ReadOnly = "true"
            }
        };

        private IEnumerable<Claim> GetUserClaims(User user)
        { 
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName),
                new Claim("USERID", user.UserId),
                new Claim("EMAILID", user.Email),
                new Claim("PHONE", user.Phone),
                new Claim("ACCESS_LEVEL", user.AccesLevel.ToUpper()),
                new Claim("READ_ONLY", user.ReadOnly.ToUpper())
            };
            return claims;
        }
```

My Controller.cs

```
        public IActionResult LoginUser(User user)
        {
            TokenProvider _tokenProvider = new TokenProvider();
            var userToken = _tokenProvider.LoginUser(user.UserId.Trim(), user.Password);
            if (userToken != null)
            {
                //Save token in session object
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("JWToken", userToken);
                bool islogin = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }
            return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
        }
```

And finally, my Index.cshtml

```
@model Colegio.Models.User
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <div class="row">
            You are Logged in as
            <span style="font-size:large;color:forestgreen;">
                @User.Identity.Name
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top:50px;">
            @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "Logoff",
            "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg rph-login-button" })
        </div>
    }
```

when i used `var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(GetUserClaims(user), token);` in my service.ch, the property IsAuthenticated was **true** but then what i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i used var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(GetUserClaims(user), token); in my service.ch, the property IsAuthenticated was true but then what i have to do?

According to your description, I couldn't understand why you use ClaimsIdentity in the service.cs login method.

The service.cs login method is used to generate the jwt token. The Controller's LoginUser method will check the user password and username and set the jwt token to the session.

But the jwt authentication will not check the session's jwt token automatically, it will check the request's request header. Since you store the jwt token into the session not set the jwt token to the client side cookie, that means  the client will not send request with jwt token header.

To solve this issue, you should write a custom middleware to read the session's jwt token and add that token into the request header.

More details ,you could refer to below codes:

Modify the startup.cs Configure method to add the custom middleware:

```
  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseSession();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var JWToken = context.Session.GetString("JWToken");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JWToken))
            {
                context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + JWToken);
            }
            await next();
        });
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Result:

[image]